# Difference between Pair and Hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, keyvaluepair

What is the necessity to introduce [Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html) class when Hashmap can do the same job?

I see Pair being introduced to Java version 8

Comment: `HasMap` is a collection of `Pairs`

Comment: What is the necessity of having a mutable Hashmap, which can hold multiple pairs, when you just need one?

Comment: In what world is `Pair` and `HashMap` doing the same thing? A `Pair` is an object for storing two values, nicknamed `key` and `value`, but might as well be named `foo` and `bar`, since they have no meaning at all to the class. A `HashMap` is an associative data structure mapping unique keys to values. They have nothing in common.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your choice of which class  to use is not just a message to your computer.  It's also a message to future developers - people who will maintain your code in the future, or even you yourself in a few months time.

By choosing whether to declare a particular variable as either `HashMap` or `Pair`, you're telling those future developers something.  It's **EITHER**

> This variable references some kind of map, which uses a hash algorithm for fast retrieval.

**OR**

> This variable references a pair of values.

That will help the future developers to understand what your code is doing.  Whereas you can certainly use a `HashMap` with a single entry instead of a `Pair`, it would be a very strange thing to do, and it would send entirely the wrong message to the future maintainers of your code.

Answer (score 7):

A pair is basically a convenient way of associating a simple key to a value. Maps do the same thing to store key-value pairs but maps stores a collection of pairs and operate them as a whole.

Number of times we have a requirement where a key-value pair shall exist on its own, for instance:

- A key-value pair needs to be passed to a method as an argument, Or
- A method needs to return just two values in form of a pair

Map complicates the things when we just need a single pair of key-value.

Answer (score -1):

`Pair<K, V>` is a part of JavaFX whereas Hashmap is in the core API.  You can most likely use `Pair` to create a hashmap implementation (I have not tested this, but I see no reason as to why not), but a `Pair` is not the same as a `HashMap`.