# What's the difference between Map.entry and Pair in Java?

Tags: java

The all have getkey, getValue methods.
Clearly Map.entry is used in a map, like map.entrySet,
but internally, are they just the same thing, implemented the same way.

Comment: What **`Pair`**?

Comment: `Pair` is a class and `Map.Entry` is an interface.

Comment: `Map.Entry` has a specific, clear context in which it is meant to be used, and clearer meanings for its parts.  Pair has...basically none of that.

Comment: I see people have said Map.Entry is an interface. That's not the question is really asking. I can ask what's the difference between AbstractMap.SimpleEntry, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry and pair, that would be too verbose. But please answer what's the difference btw those two entries and pair

Answer (score 2):

They should be very similar but `Pair` is defined in the `javafx` library whereas `Map.Entry` is defined in the `java.util` library.

The basic gist of both objects are some like:

```
public class Pair<K, V> implements Serializable {
    private K key;
    public K getKey() { return key; }
    
    private V value;
    public V getValue() { return value; }
}
```

`Map.Entry` is mainly used to store a collection of key-value pairs that can be iterated over whereas `Pair` is mainly used for storing single key-value pairs.

[Here is another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45396342/difference-between-pair-and-hashmap) detailing further differences between `Pair` and `Map` implementations

Comment: There is nothing "internal" in `Map.Entry` whatsoever. It is an inferface; it has no internals.

Answer (score 1):

## Interface versus class

One difference is that one is a class while the other is an interface.

[`javafx.util.Pair<K,V>`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.base/javafx/util/Pair.html) is a concrete class. To instantiate a `Pair`, use `new`. To access the class you’ll need to add the OpenJFX libraries to your project, or else use a JDK that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries such as ZuluFX or LibericaFX.

In contrast, [`java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is an interface. To instantiate a `Map.Entry`, you’ll need to choose a class that implements that interface. Java comes with two such classes: `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` and `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`.

Alternatively, in Java 9+ you can call the static method [`Map.entry( key , value )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) to get an unmodifiable `Map.Entry` object. The concrete class is unspecified.

You asked:

> but internally, are they just the same thing

An interface has no implementation, so no “internals” on `Map.Entry`. As for the implementation details of the concrete classes, we should not really care. All we care about as calling programmers is the contract they promise to fulfill as specified in the JavaDoc.

If you are curious about the implementation details, both are open-source. So you can browse their implementation. Both are found on the OpenJDK project site. But remember that the implementors are free to change their respective implementations between versions, as long as the contract is respected.

- [`Map.Entry` source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Map.java) at [OpenJDK on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk)
- [`Pair` source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/javafx/util/Pair.java) at [OpenJFX on GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx)

## Original intent

`Pair` is meant to be used in JavaFX.

`Entry` is meant to be used with `Map`.

You can certainly use either class outside of those contexts. But such use can be confusing to other programmers reading your code. Consider adding a brief explanation in your code comments.

## Record

Instead of using `Pair` outside of JavaFX, or using `Entry` outside of a `Map`, in many cases it makes more sense to use the new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature to make your own purpose-built class for pairing in one short simple line.

For example:

```
Record( Person person , Color favoriteColor ) {}
```

Records can even be defined locally (as can interfaces and enums in Java 16+).

Comment: For what it’s worth, there is now a [Map.entry(key, value)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) method.

Comment: @VGR Good point. I'll add a mention.